# Custom sort comparator for javascript string

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a custom comparator for sorting some strings which doesnt work as expected for sorting strings in descending order.

```js
var list = document.getElementById('mylist');

var items = list.childNodes;
var itemsArr = [];
for (var i in items) {
  if (items[i].nodeType == 1) { // get rid of the whitespace text nodes
    itemsArr.push(items[i]);
  }
}
var sortOrder = "DESC";

itemsArr.sort(function(a, b) {
  switch (sortOrder) {
    case "ASC":
      var val = a.innerHTML.localeCompare(b.innerHTML);
      break;
    case "DESC":
      var val = a.innerHTML.localeCompare(b.innerHTML);
      if (val === 1)
        val = -1;
      if (val === -1)
        val = 1;
      break;

  }
  return val
});

/*itemsArr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.innerHTML == b.innerHTML
          ? 0
          : (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML ? 1 : -1);
});*/

for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; ++i) {
  list.appendChild(itemsArr[i]);
}
```

```html
<ul id="mylist">
  <li id="list-item3">Service</li>
  <li id="list-item4">Vendor</li>
  <li id="list-item2">Service_Type</li>
  <li id="list-item1">Call_Date</li>
  <li id="list-item3">Customer Sat Rating</li>
  <li id="list-item4">TTA</li>
  <li id="list-item2">Support_Rep</li>
  <li id="list-item1">Source_State</li>
  <li id="list-item3">Severity</li>
  <li id="list-item4">Customer_Type</li>
  <li id="list-item2">CALL ID</li>
  <li id="list-item1">Resolved_Ontime</li>
  <li id="list-item2">Product</li>
  <li id="list-item1">Minutes_On_Phone</li>
</ul>
```

For a different data I sorted earlier it worked fine for both ascending and descending. For the current html data it doesnt. Can someone please show where I am incorrect?

Comment: You should not have duplicate id's, they mess up the lookup table for the DOM.

Comment: To do descending sort with `.localeCompare()` you just need to use the unary `-` operator: `val = -val;`

Comment: In my working code, I do not have duplicate ID's. This html snippet is for stackoverflow. Still Ill edit it

Comment: @Pointy: Any small snippet you can point me to, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting it to DESC and then right back again:

```
case "DESC":
  var val = a.innerHTML.localeCompare(b.innerHTML);
  if (val === 1)
    val = -1;
  if (val === -1)
    val = 1;
  break;
```

Change it to:

```
case "DESC":
  var val = -1 * a.innerHTML.localeCompare(b.innerHTML);
  break;
```

Comment: You don't need the `*` operator. Just apply the `-` unary operator to the return value: `-a.innerHTML.localeCompare(b.innerHTML)`